# How I can use [UseCase] attribute without CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges()

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need audit changes for my entity, and I need use custom reason message.
I can use it by [UseCase] attribute, but with it I need use `await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();` manually like in [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History).

How I can handle it, without manually call `await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();` ?

Comment: Audit logs are created when changes are saved. To bind the disposed reason to only the entities changed within the method until the unit of work completes, you would need a pretty convoluted way to iterate through the active DB contexts and entities. You would also need to consider and properly handle the case of different properties of an entity being changed in another `[UseCase]` since you can only bind one reason to the audit log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still have same question. It is possible to use  [UseCase] without _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync(); in last line in method ?

Comment: You can implement it. I've already described how, but it's not worth it.

Comment: Ok. thanks, I was thinking abp have some mechanism for it.